# Is really Black and White display mode on AMOLED can save energy

Tags: android

As the title question, is it really save energy? 
as we know the white color is come from maximum light in RGB which mean maximum power to draw it in display.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions and your question is not about programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this article: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-black-is/

---

New advances in LCD technologies could eventually validate the belief that black is better. Newer types of **LCD include a dynamic dimming capability** that changes the strength of the backlight based on the image being displayed. Heap also points out that many of the new monitor technologies such as LCDs backlit with light-emitting diodes (LED), plasma screens and organic **LED screens do not have a constant backlight** "so we will see larger savings with Blackle as these new monitors replace the CCFL LCDs," he says.

---

**For those who've graduated to thinner LCD models, black screens are actually sucking up more energy then their white counterparts.**

and from wikipedia:

---

The amount of power the display consumes varies significantly depending on the colour and brightness shown. As an example, one commercial QVGA OLED display consumes **0.3 watts** while showing **white text on a black background**, but **more than 0.7 watts** showing **black text on a white background**
...

### **Because the black pixels actually turn off, AMOLED also has contrast ratios that are significantly better than LCD**

so it really depends how a screen treat it's constant back light.. seems like OLED and therefor AMOLED perform better then LCD screens on that matter

Answer (score -1):

Apparently it is true.  As I understand it, modern amoled screens work by only lighting up the pixels that are needed.  This is in contrast to LCD screens where there is a constant backlight that is always on.  In LCD screens they achieve a black pixel not by turning off the backlight but rather by filtering out any light from passing through a given pixel.  Therefore the energy used by the backlight is not any less, the light output just doesn't make it out of the panel and to your vision.
AMOLED otoh actually lights only lit pixels.  Blacks are represented by not turning on the pixel in the first place.  This does amount to an energy savings commensurate with the amount of black on the screen.  More black = more pixels NOT turned on = more energy NOT used = energy "saved"

Here is a link to a basic test done by [Android Authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/black-amoled-display-power-saving-541984/).   However basic the test is, the results are pretty clear..